# Linux crashes after calling inet_csk_reqsk_queue_drop_and_put()

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

I modified the Linux kernel code so it drops the first TCP connection request if the SYN backlog contains more than 9 connection requests as shown bellow, but the system hangs when 8 connections arrive.
The last output is

> `Test : 3- SYN Queue Length = 8`

The original code is [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6316).
Modified code:

```
tcp_rsk(req)->tfo_listener = false;
    if (!want_cookie) {
        struct inet_connection_sock *icsk = inet_csk(sk);
        struct request_sock_queue *queue = &icsk->icsk_accept_queue;
        printk("Test : 1- SYN Queue Length = %d\n", inet_csk_reqsk_queue_len(sk));
        inet_csk_reqsk_queue_hash_add(sk, req,
            tcp_timeout_init((struct sock *)req));
        printk("Test : 2- SYN Queue Length = %d\n", inet_csk_reqsk_queue_len(sk));
        // This is where i drop connection request
        if (net->ipv4.sysctl_max_syn_backlog - inet_csk_reqsk_queue_len(sk) < 124) {
            struct request_sock *first_request_sock = queue->rskq_accept_head;
            printk("Test : First condition\n");
            if (net->ipv4.sysctl_max_syn_backlog - inet_csk_reqsk_queue_len(sk) < 120) {
                inet_csk_reqsk_queue_drop_and_put(sk, first_request_sock);
                printk("Test : Second condition\n");
            }               
        }
        printk("Test : 3- SYN Queue Length = %d\n", inet_csk_reqsk_queue_len(sk));
    }
        
    af_ops->send_synack(sk, dst, &fl, req, &foc,
                !want_cookie ? TCP_SYNACK_NORMAL :
                       TCP_SYNACK_COOKIE);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"crashes"*? Do you have some stack trace and `BUG` description of crash?

Comment: it freezes, i can't do anything.

Comment: *"it freezes"* - If you want to understand the exact reason you should somehow access the stack trace. There are a lot of ways described in Internet. By the way what is the reason of trying to do some thing that is already implemented in kernel?

Comment: Just set `backlog` to `9` through the `listen()`-call and check it. Smart people write Linux kernel code, no need to add any rubbish.

Comment: when i set the backlog to 9, it's going to ignore incoming requests, but i want to delete old ones, also i want to control how many requests i will delete and the criteria of choosing those requests.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, why the last 3 lines of the output is not : Test : 3- SYN Queue Length = 8, Test : 2- SYN Queue Length = 9, Test : First condition ? do i need to flush the output stream like i do in regular c programs using fflush() ?

Comment: printk is normally synchronous but will defer to avoid deadlocks or inifinite recursion.  I don't think that fflush would work.  Are you holding a lock or expecting a long interrupt at that point in the code?

Comment: no, i'm not doing any of the above

Comment: @stark All it is inside BH-disabled-section: [`tcp_rcv_state_process()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L5829)

Comment: Decison is made here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/kernel/printk/printk_safe.c#L361

Comment: Thank you "red0ct" and "stark", everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the variable first_request_sock contains NULL due to an error in my logic, that's way the system freezes, and as @stark and @red0ct explained, the printk defer to avoid deadlocks or inifinite recursion that's why it couldn't print the three lines mentioned in the comments.